# Recorrer archivo csv y tomar datos de celdas

Tags: c#, csv

Como puedo recorrer un archivo `cvs`, tengo esta estructura:

```
        1           2   
A     NOMBRE,     JOSE  
B    APELLIDO,     PEREZ
```

Lo que requiero es tomar los datos, como JOSE Y PEREZ

```
    string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.csv");
for (int i = 0; i < lineas.Length; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Saludos, por curiosidad ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: esa estructura no es un csv, faltan el separador, si usa la coma o el punto y coma  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas

Comment: si es un archivo csv entones el A y B, igual que el 1 y 2 que has definido en el ejemplo no deberian estar

Comment: la estructura correcta tampoco implica que definas NOMBRE y APELLIDO como pare de una columna, tu csv solo deria ser: JOSE, PEREZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`archivo.csv`

```
NOMBRE,     JOSE  
APELLIDO,     PEREZ
```

`codigo`

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"archivo.csv");
            for (int i = 0; i < lineas.Length; i++)
            {
                var data = lineas[i].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if ((data?.Length ?? 0) >= 2) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(data[1]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```